# pvcreate does not work: Device /dev/sda3 not found

Tags: centos, lvm, partition-table

As I recall I accidentally removed partition with fdisk and left changes which I did on LVM, then I did restart and Centos was not able to boot normally, it booted to Dracut.. It is my fault that I did experiments without making VM backup.

Currently it shows that device is missing: Couldn't find device with uuid Tuio4I-anaw-oBDD-Wisp-9uAZ-PYSF-YNg1KF:
[image]

Tried adding it, but it says device is not found:
[image]

Checked devices with blkid command and shows /dev/sda3 is not present and I guess this is the reason why *pvcreate* is not working:

[image]

Also tried to get rid of unknown device, but did not work:
[image]

Is it possible to add sda3 back from dracut, because fdisk command is not present or maybe my finding are not valid? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you didn't recreate the partition. And please, don't post screenshots of text that you could copy&paste. Just copy&paste it.

Comment: Yes, partition is missing, but fdisk is not working on Dracut, hence I cannot recreate. I need some other way how to create it. Regarding screenshot, yes, it is not good for community, but I cannot copy paste, because VMvare Remote Console does not provide this possibility.

Comment: Then boot your VM into an Linux Live Image (for example grml, booted from an ISO file) and use this for administering your file systems.